# Is it OK to ask others to upvote own answer as a "thank you"?

Tags: discussion, support, voting, thanks

Sometimes I have a situation that a single comment solves the whole problem. The person who asked the question is thankful for the solution and often says that they will delete their question (because the issue is solved and/or there are no answers on that question).

My question is: is it OK (permissible within the rules of this site) to ask this person that if they want, they can upvote my other answer as a "thank you" for solving his issue.

Is it OK? Or could I end up in trouble for this?

Comment: No. Upvoting a user's other posts as gratitude counts as [serial voting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126829/349538) and is against the rules. Post an answer expanding on your comment instead and ask them to accept that answer.

Comment: @DonaldDuck Serial voting? Even if I ask for **one** upvote?

Comment: Votes should be on content, not on users. If your comment helped them, you can write it as an answer and they can upvote/accept *that* answer. Voting on a completely unrelated post just to express gratitude for something else than that post is considered voting fraud and is against the rules, even if it's just one post.

Comment: “My question is: is it OK (permissible within the rules of this site) to ask this person that if they want, they can upvote my other answer as a "thank you" for solving his issue.” - **It absolutely is not “ok” to ask someone to upvote or accept your answer.** I make a habit flagging any comment that even comes close to asking for an accept or an upvote

Comment: This one is self-answerable by researching what comments are used for - comments being the only real way to do this outside of chat.

Answer (score 22):

> Is it OK?

No. Up and downvotes are to communicate the usefulness of a post by the judgement of the voter. They are not meant to be used for anything else. We're not going to influence their judgement by all kind of comments.

> Or could I end up in trouble for this?

I hope so. I certainly don't want to see:

- thousands of comments begging OPs to leave a "Thank you" vote
- thousands of posts with a skewed score because we now have (un)usefulness and thank you votes to cater for.

Counter question: Is it okay to ask others to downvote this awful answer because you're not thankful for it?

If anything, Up and Down should go both ways.

Answer (score 14):

No. Upvoting a specific user's other posts as gratitude is considered [voting fraud](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126829/349538) and is against the rules. Voting fraud is a reason to suspend users, so if a moderator sees you doing this, you will probably end up in trouble.

Even if it's just one post, the same idea still applies: votes should be on content, not on users. The idea of Stack Overflow's voting system is that the best answers should get the most upvotes and rise to the top. If people start voting on users instead of content, that would break this system.

In your case, you should post an answer expanding on your comment. If you do that, it's perfectly fine (and even encouraged) for the user to upvote and accept your answer, since the content of that answer actually helped them.

Comment: [Privileges - Vote up](/help/privileges/vote-up) also is a good reference: "Posts should be voted on based on the content in the post rather than the person who wrote it. Voting for specific people, whether you know them or not, can negatively impact our ranking system."